# Votes based on opinion, not correct answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting

This may be more of a rant, but hoping it sparks a discussion. This may be related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16236/when-should-correct-answers-get-downvoted), but I'm wondering what people think about questions that contain "questionable" ethical material and users voting based on their opinion of that material.

For example, I answered a [question about Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894526/fathers-day-coming-up-can-i-get-the-profile-of-a-facebook-users-father/2894536#2894536) recently that had been voted down heavily because (seemingly) users felt that what the user wanted to accomplish was some kind of abuse of their privacy. I felt it was a valid question since it is part of the Facebook API. One of the answers that was actually an incorrect answer was voted up 6 times (now thankfully others have voted it down 4 times) just for the poster's opinion on the topic, not for his/her answer. My answer was voted down as well even though correct.

Interestingly enough, seems like the question now has -6 votes and +6 votes, so maybe this is a moot point and it'll all equal out when the initial troll/flaming votes die down.

I'd love a way to "flag" an answer to be "Plain Wrong" and if it got enough votes, would be removed or marked as "wrong" in some way. Maybe that's a bit fascist. Donno. Thoughts?

I guess votes based on "liking" something versus it being "correct" annoy me. And posts that contain XKCD comics. That's all.

Comment: Check out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45896/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36397/ and possibly other similar questions on the topic

Comment: [Obligatory](http://xkcd.com/386/) since you mentioned XKCD...

Comment: @ccornet: please include the titles in your URLs, so it's possible to see which questions they are without actually opening them.
More related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17170/handling-questions-that-are-clearly-trying-to-break-some-kind-of-policy-tos-etc
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18098/should-there-be-a-close-option-for-questions-regarding-to-some-illegal-activity
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21706/unethical-questions-should-answer
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17763/ethical-questions-about-hackers-cheaters-and-lusers

Comment: ...and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18648/are-we-allowed-to-ask-questions-about-programming-ethics-on-so
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36397/technically-valid-answers-that-raise-questions-of-morality
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25286/how-far-should-we-go-in-judging-question-ethics

Comment: @Ether lol, thanks. close it already! ;)

Comment: If you liked the Facebook question, you'll *love* [this one.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671444/copy-on-delete-of-browser-history)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A well stated argument, even when in support of an incorrect conclusion, has a serious advantage over any other argument. Further, appealing to popular opinion often allows total disregard for logic.

My advice would be to counter popular misinformation with a solid, well put together explanation. In this case, it would also help to add a disclaimer about privacy concerns, to avoid any misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4):

Down votes are plenary: people can cast them for any reason (or indeed for no reason).

Now, *I* would always comment if casting a down vote to mean "you shouldn't do this" rather than "this is not right", but that is *still* my privilege.

In any case, there is only one downvote there, so it's not like you got hammered. Just move on...

Comment: I'm not concerned about my rep at all. Was more concerned for the poster who got initially hammered. Was concerned that a great question could get buried with -6 votes (I personally usually skip reading a question if it has tons of negative votes).